# transistor characteristics - Ube0 number meaning

Tags: transistors, datasheet, voltage-divider, maximum-ratings

i'm trying to guess meaning of value marked as Ube0 in datasheets. (datasheet adress: http://www.datasheetarchive.com/dlmain/Datasheets-36/DSA-700258.pdf, the transistor I want to use is Tesla KF-508). I want to regulate secondary circuit by voltage divider on base. Does this value means that max allowed voltage on base is 7 volts and I must design voltage divider to not allow more than 7 volts and current no more than 2.2 mA ?? (computed from measured parameter h21e = 233, max current that I want trought collector = 0.5 A)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U<sub>BEO</sub> is the base to emitter voltage with unconnected or "open" collector terminal.

A bipolar junction transistor has three terminals, **b**ase, **c**ollector and **e**mitter. Whichever terminal is not connected for the rating is replaced with **o**pen when left unconnected. Hence similar identifiers for U<sub>CBO</sub>, U<sub>CEO</sub>.

U<sub>EBO</sub> = -U<sub>BEO</sub> = 7V means that the emitter voltage referenced to the base voltage can be 7V maximum. Often there is a "max" squeezed (U<sub>EBO,max</sub>) in to indicate it is a maximum rating.

If you exceed that voltage the base to emitter diode will break down (avalanche). When carefully used this mode of operation can be used as a white noise generator, when uncareful the transistor will be destroyed.

Comment: Ok, thank You much. I have just made simple motor RPM regulator from two NPN transistors and some DJ's mixpult-crossfader styled straight potentiometer for peugeot 205 heating fan and if I dissmiss the truth about effectivity of circuit where the second NPN transistor with heatsink from CPU is 2nd heating by inself, It is working perfectly :D PS is there any system to add Karma / thanks button or it is just "accepted answer"?

Comment: @Kovo Accept and upvote is the way to say thanks on stackexchange.